# How To get folder path of create a folder inside a Album in iOS iPhone Using Xamarin form

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I have created a folder inside a album using PHAsset. But I want to get a folder path of that. Is this possible to get a folder path inside album in iOS.
I am trying to get recent folder path that's also returns "".
So I don't know how to get a exact folder path of create a folder inside a Album in iOS.

Please help

Comment: you can't write directly to the album using paths

Comment: I want to open the image from photos inside the app. So that I want album path

Comment: @Karthika the technology behind the photo album is not like that as Jason said. Aside the fact that you can't access that part of the disk directly even if you could Apple could organize files in a different way, it is not completely necessary to have a folder on the disk in order to have an album in the app, there are other possible implementations too.

Comment: the user needs to allow you to access images from the photo album

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the photo, what you can do in xamarin is use **mediapicker**,the class lets a user pick or take a photo or video on the device.

For more detail, you can refer to this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/media-picker?tabs=ios

Comment: I want to select multiple Images, so I am using media gallery. Media picker returns  the album path and full path. In case of Media gallery it didn't return path. that's the only prblm I am facing to get a path.

Comment: you can copy and save the file in where you want